# Build a yes/no form in teams with adaptive cards

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I wanted to build a messaging extension in Teams that sends an adaptive card to everyone in the chat of that team. I've already created and send the card. Now, I want to get all the responses and count the number of yes/no. I understand that the magic appends in the "Action.Submit" field, but I don't know if its necessary to use other technology (power automate/DB/...) to get this simple task done.
Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Given that you have already build messaging extension you should be able to listen to "Action.Submit". Let me know if you are still blocked on this & need help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you planning to show that data on the same yes/no form.
If yes, you can bind all responses and yes/no count data with "data" part of button in card payload.

If you have lots of data responses, we can not bind with Adaptive Card as we have a payload limit at around 28 KB.
So in this case you need to use other technology like power automate/BI to show all responses.